# Slow Output in Outlook via Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm using Powershell to access Outlook Mails by creating COM Object.
When I search for particular Mail . PowerShell Iterates through all the mails due to which my output result is really slow and taking very long time.

I have already tried using Descending paramater in Sort-Object or filtering out by date but still results are slow.

```
$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$inbox = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$find = $inbox.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$find.Items | Where-Object{$_.SentOn -gt '27-Oct-2019 12:00 PM'}| Select- 
Object -Property Subject,SentOn
```

Can someone please help me to generate faster results or provide a way to filter my search for particular time period.

Comment: If you `sort` the items in your inbox, it does not change the fact that powershell has to go through all of your e-mails. I guess that you have many e-mails in your inbox? If I run your code on my system with less than 100 mails in it, it only takes 0.5 seconds...

Comment: @Dan is there any way through which I can achieve quick results or my script iterates from newest mail to older mail?

Comment: The Outlook COM interface is very slow. If you are using an Exchange server you can use EWS which is very performant.

Comment: That has not much to do with the COM interface. Use folder filters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-filter-and-efficiently-enumerate-items-in-a-folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never loop through all items in your code. After all, you wouldn't write a `SELECT` query in SQL without a `WHERE` clause, would you?

Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` to let the store provider do the job.

Comment: `Find` and `Restrict` only seem to use a string to "filter" the emails.. Is it possible to filter the emails by a date with these functions?

Comment: Of course - you can use datetime properties too, e.g. [ReceivedTime] < '10/29/2019'

Comment: That's awesome. Did not know that you can use it like this `$x= $find.Items.Find("[SentOn] < '10/29/2019'")`and its lightning fast. It only took about 18ms, where my "solution" still took around 180ms... You already got my upvote

Answer (score 1):

From the comment from @bluuf I looked into the EWS (exchange web service) and came up with this solution and its about 50% faster than your script.. Maybe it helps for you

```
$startDate = Get-Date
$MailboxSMTP = "peter.parker@home.com"  
$dllpath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Mashup\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)

$service = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1)
$service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$service.AutodiscoverURL($mailboxSMTP)

$mbMailbox = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Mailbox($mailboxSMTP)

$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
write-host "Number or unread Messages : " $inbox.UnreadCount 

$emails = $inbox.FindItems(10000) | Where-Object { $_.DateTimeSent -gt '27-Oct-2019 12:00 PM'}
$endDate = Get-Date

New-TimeSpan -Start $startDate -End $endDate
```

Found the script here https://www.msxfaq.de/code/testews.htm

---

EDIT:

You can filter the results with EWS in a similar way as in @Dmitry solution

```
write-host "Number or unread Messages : " $inbox.UnreadCount 

$view = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(1)
$x = $inbox.FindItems($(New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::DateTimeReceived, '2019-10-27')),$view)
```

Or you can use it to filter for different attributes

```
$filter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::IsRead, $false)
```

Or

```
$filter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsLessThanOrEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::DateTimeReceived,'2019-10-10')
$x = $inbox.FindItems($filter,$view)
```